# Enter keyboard event not working properly on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using IE11 and I am trying to use the Enter keyboard event to trigger a function.
I am attempting to log the key events with a function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
   console.log('IS ENTER', e.keyCode);
});
```

It logs all of the keyboard events on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE it doesn't log in the console the Enter event.

```
var closeWynPopupKeyb = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 71 || e.keyCode === 13) {
        closeWynPopup(e);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

That function above works properly on the other browsers.

Do you have an idea of what is wrong?

Comment: is there an error in the console?

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz not actually.

Comment: ===> `e.which` https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1758 about permanently broken IE11 key events impacting jQuery. Perhaps @blex method will work?

Comment: Why are you preventing up? It would make more sense to prevent it on down.

Comment: I tested in IE11 and this actually works for me. Can you post all of your code?

Comment: Is IE11 in Edge mode or some form of quirks mode?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on IE 11, using jQuery 1.12.4, 2.2.4 and 3.3.1 and works at a glance:

```
<script>
    $(window).on('keyup', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.keyCode); // logs 13
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly on any other browser hooking the event to the document or document.body, but not on IE11. You need to hook the event to the window itself (that will also work on the other major browsers).